# simple_form_for partial file with same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am new to ruby on rails I am having a view which have partial file in that partial file also i have to render same object but iam getting error .

Here are my code

```
app/view/customer/_form.html.erb
 <%= simple_form_for(@customer) do |f| %> 
 <%= f.input :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name', label: 'Customer First Name' %>
 <%= f.input :last_name, placeholder: 'Last name', label: 'Customer Last Name' %>
 <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'user@domain.com', label: 'Customer Email' %>
<%= render :partial=> other_fields,:f => f %>   
<%end%>

app/views/customer/_other_fields.html.erb

<%= f.input :user_name, label: 'User Name' %>
<%= f.input :password, label: 'Password' %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
```

I am getting error like

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= render :partial=> other_fields, :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

Comment: yes its working but after clicking create if i check the parameters whatever field we have in partial those fields value coming empty.

Comment: just check this out when i raised my params i got this output                                                                 {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"16CPJVX4L+VShLxy8CAj17IRfr7bUe+cMEI365mHLEg=", "customer"=>{"customer_name"=>"asd", "first_name"=>"asd", "last_name"=>"asd", "email"=>"asd@gmail.com",  "user_name"=>"", "password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create customer", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"customers"}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= render :partial=> other_fields, :object => @customer, :locals => {:f => f} %>
```